# What is the best way to create a "stop progress" button like in Safari's Downloads window?

Tags: cocoa, macos

The [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://web.archive.org/web/20100831154127/http://developer.apple.com:80/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIcons/XHIGIcons.html) say:

> In the Downloads window, Safari uses the free-standing NSImageNameStopProgressFreestandingTemplate image inline with a progress indicator to allow users to stop an in-progress download.

[image: Safari Downloads Window]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/art/sys_freestanding.jpg))</sub>

The [NSImage documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20100901132331/http://developer.apple.com:80/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says something similar. However, creating an `NSButton` using `NSImageNameStopProgressFreestandingTemplate` and `NSShadowlessSquareBezelStyle` produces something like this:

[image: NSImageNameStopProgressFreestandingTemplate]

Unfortunately, this button does not match the "stop progress" buttons for the built-in Mac OS X applications:

1. It's much darker than the buttons in Finder and Safari, and slightly darker than the one in iCal.
2. It doesn't change color on rollover/hover like the buttons in Finder, Safari, and iCal.

Is there an `NSButton` setting I'm missing that would make the system-provided image look "right"?

Failing that, is it better to use `NSImageNameStopProgressFreestandingTemplate` and look "wrong," or to write a button subclass and bundle some TIFFs, which is what most applications (including Apple's) seem to be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official answer, as of Mac OS X 10.7, seems to be to use `NSImageNameStopProgressFreestandingTemplate` and `NSInlineBezelStyle`. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSInlineBezelStyle) says:

> The inline bezel style contains a solid round-rect border background. It can be used to create an "unread" indicator in an outline view, or another inline button in a tableview, such as a stop progress button in a download panel.

This produces a button that's slightly darker than in Safari, but not as dark as with the other bezel styles. It does not change color on hover, but perhaps Apple is phasing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The docs on `[NSImage setTemplate:]` suggest varying the alpha to determine how dark it is.  However, I'm not sure how to do that when you're not directly drawing the image.  I don't see a better way than writing your own subclass of NSButton or maybe NSButtonCell.